# Flutter - How to parsed nested json to a class with generics?

Tags: json, parsing, generics, dart, flutter

I'm wondering how can I parse a nested json to a class with generic types. My intention is to wrap responses from the backend (like loginRespose that contains a token) with a code and a message

I have

```
class BaseResponse<T>{
  int code;
  String message;
  T responseObject;

  BaseResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson)
    : code = parsedJson['Code'],
      message = parsedJson['Message'],
      responseObject = T.fromJson(parsedJson['ResponseObject']); //This is what I'd like to do
}
```

Obviously the last line throws an error because T doesn't has a named constructor "fromJson".
I tried adding some restrictions to the Type but I didn't find any solutions. Do you have any idea on how to pull this off?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. There's no interface for constructors and flutter disabled `dart:mirror`. Maybe store inside `responseObject` the json object directly. And parse it individually. Or you could pass a custom deserializer to `fromJson` ctor

Comment: @RémiRousselet Thank you for your answer. Would you mind on exemplifying  some of those solutions? Thank you very much

Comment: Found a better solution. Here it is :)

Comment: You might want to look at built_value package. It promises "any object model that you can design can be serialized, including full use of generics and interfaces. Some other libraries require concrete types or do not fully support generics."

Comment: @CarsonHolzheimer the biggest problem here is not serialization, but deserialization.

Comment: @RémiRousselet built_value equally supports deserialization. It's not straightforward but it is possible to do what Sebastian requires.

Answer (score 15):

You can't do such thing, at least not in flutter. As `dart:mirror` is disabled and there's no interface for classes constructors.

You'll have to take a different route.

I'll recommend using POO instead. You would here give up on deserializing `responseObject` from your `BaseResponse`. And then have subclass of `BaseResponse` handles this deserialization

Typically you'd have one subclass per type:

```
class IntResponse extends BaseResponse<int> {
  IntResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) : super._fromJson(json) {
    this.responseObject = int.parse(json["Hello"]);
  }
}
```

You can then hide this mess away by adding a custom factory constructor on `BaseResponse` to make it more convenient to use.

```
class BaseResponse<T> {
  int code;
  String message;
  T responseObject;

  BaseResponse._fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson)
      : code = parsedJson['Code'],
        message = parsedJson['Message'];

  factory BaseResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (T == int) {
      return IntResponse.fromJson(json) as BaseResponse<T>;
    }
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Then either instantiate the wanted type directly, or use the factory constructor :

```
final BaseResponse foo = BaseResponse.fromJson<int>({"Hello": "42", "Code": 42, "Message": "World"});
```

Comment: What if `T` is nested like a `List<int>`?

Comment: @Frenco Please check my answer

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this with the [built_value](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/built_value) package (you'll also need [built_value_generator](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/built_value_generator) and [build_runner](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/build_runner)). Your class will look something like this:

```
part 'base_response.g.dart';

abstract class BaseResponse<T> implements Built<BaseResponse<T>, BaseResponseBuilder<T>> {
  int code;
  String message;
  T responseObject;

  factory BaseResponse([updates(BaseResponseBuilder<T> b)]) = _$BaseResponse<T>;

  static Serializer<BaseResponse> get serializer => _$baseResponseSerializer;
}
```

You will have to run `flutter packages pub run build_runner build` to make the generated file. Then you use it like this:

```
BaseResponse baseResponse = serializers.deserialize(
  json.decode(response.body),
  specifiedType: const FullType(BaseResponse, const [FullType(ConcreteTypeGoesHere)])
);
```

There's just one more bit of boilerplate you have to take care of. You need another file called serializers.dart. You need to manually add all the classes you want to deserialize here, and also an addBuilderFactory function for each class that takes a type parameter - and for each concrete type you want to use.

```
part 'serializers.g.dart';

@SerializersFor(const [
  BaseResponse,
  ConcreteTypeGoesHere,
])
final Serializers serializers = (_$serializers.toBuilder()
      ..addBuilderFactory(
        FullType(BaseResponse, const [const FullType(ConcreteTypeGoesHere)]),
        () => new BaseResponseBuilder<ConcreteTypeGoesHere>()
      )
      ..addPlugin(StandardJsonPlugin()))
    .build();
```

Then re-run `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`

Makes me wish for Gson... :S

Comment: "Gjson" is kinda irrelevant here. This boilerplate is mostly due to `dart:mirror` being disabled. gjson would have the same problem

Comment: Yeah I wish ```dart:mirrors``` was available so we could have a simple solution for json deserializing

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach:

```
class Wrapper<T, K> {
  bool? isSuccess;
  T? data;

  Wrapper({
    this.isSuccess,
    this.data,
  });

  factory Wrapper.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$WrapperFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$WrapperToJson(this);
}

Wrapper<T, K> _$WrapperFromJson<T, K>(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Wrapper<T, K>(
    isSuccess: json['isSuccess'] as bool?,
    data: json['data'] == null ? null : Generic.fromJson<T, K>(json['data']),
  );
}

class Generic {
  /// If T is a List, K is the subtype of the list.
  static T fromJson<T, K>(dynamic json) {
    if (json is Iterable) {
      return _fromJsonList<K>(json) as T;
    } else if (T == LoginDetails) {
      return LoginDetails.fromJson(json) as T;
    } else if (T == UserDetails) {
      return UserDetails.fromJson(json) as T;
    } else if (T == Message) {
      return Message.fromJson(json) as T;
    } else if (T == bool || T == String || T == int || T == double) { // primitives
      return json;
  } else {
      throw Exception("Unknown class");
    }
  }

  static List<K> _fromJsonList<K>(List<dynamic> jsonList) {
    return jsonList?.map<K>((dynamic json) => fromJson<K, void>(json))?.toList();
  }
}
```

In order to add support for a new data model, simply add it to Generic.fromJson:

```
else if (T == NewDataModel) {
  return NewDataModel.fromJson(json) as T;
}
```

This works with either generic objects:

```
Wrapper<Message, void>.fromJson(someJson)
```

Or lists of generic objects:

```
Wrapper<List<Message>, Message>.fromJson(someJson)
```