# How to parse nested JSON in built_value library

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I'm trying to parse this JSON object using built_value library, I managed to get the base response

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "",
    "data": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 30,
                "id_f": "D01"
            },
            {
                "id": 31,
                "id_f": "D02"
            },
        ],
        "first_page_url": "http://192.168.1.120:8000/api/requests/driver?page=1",
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 2,
        "last_page_url": "http://192.168.1.120:8000/api/requests/driver?page=2",
        "next_page_url": "http://192.168.1.120:8000/api/requests/driver?page=2",
        "path": "http://192.168.1.120:8000/api/requests/driver",
        "per_page": 20,
        "prev_page_url": null,
        "to": 20,
        "total": 34
    }
}
```

I managed to parse the BaseResponse which I found out from this helpful [anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890211/10379729)

Put I got stuck because I want to finally get an object like this

```
BaseResponse<PaginateResponse<BuiltList<Deliveries>>>
```

Is there any solution to do that with the awesome built_value library?