# How to deserialize a string to a object and then set as a generic in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, generics, serialization, json-deserialization

So I have this api call that have a response in the form of: boolean:successful, int:responseCode, String:reponse and T:Data. The Data is a generic, I could be string, int, DataModel etc. My issue is I can not conver the Json or String from of Data to an object as the type is generic. I try to have the deseralization for a data model called event resource. and it works if I do `EventResource.fromJson(json['Data'])` but I can not set that to `Data`. I have looked on stack overflow and found this one post similar to mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51575371/flutter-how-to-parsed-nested-json-to-a-class-with-generics). But when I try to implement the answer it fails stating that it can not find the constructor `_fromJson` even though I had one.

This is how I call `fromJson`:

`ResponseModel responseModel = ResponseModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));`

My Class (ResponseModel):

```
import 'EventResource.dart';
import 'dart:convert' show json;

class ResponseModel<T> {
  var successful;

  int responseCode;

  String response;

  T Data;

  ResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    successful = json['successful'];
    responseCode = json['responseCode'];
    response = json['response'];
    Data = Data is EventResource? EventResource.fromJson(json['Data']) :json['Data']; // this is what I want but cant get to work
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {

    return {
      'successful': successful,
      'responseCode': responseCode,
      'response': response,
      'Data': Data,
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So after sending some time on this I realized rather than have `Data` be a generic it  could be assigned the type `var` and it would take in any data and we could easily cast it with out having the issues of casting generics etc.

```
class ResponseModel {
  var successful;

  int responseCode;

  String response;

  var Data;

  ResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    successful = json['successful'];
    responseCode = json['responseCode'];
    response = json['response'];
    Data = Data is EventResource? EventResource.fromJson(json['Data']) :json['Data'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {

    return {
      'successful': successful,
      'responseCode': responseCode,
      'response': response,
      'Data': Data,
    };
  }

}
```